# No variable to save error in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to save the model and then reuse it for classifying my images but unfortunately i am getting errors in restoring the model that i have saved.

**The code in which model has been created** :

```
# Deep Learning
# =============
# 
# Assignment 4
# ------------

# In[25]:

# These are all the modules we'll be using later. Make sure you can import them
# before proceeding further.
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
from six.moves import range


# In[37]:

pickle_file = 'notMNIST.pickle'

with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as f:
  save = pickle.load(f)
  train_dataset = save['train_dataset']
  train_labels = save['train_labels']
  valid_dataset = save['valid_dataset']
  valid_labels = save['valid_labels']
  test_dataset = save['test_dataset']
  test_labels = save['test_labels']
  del save  # hint to help gc free up memory
  print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
  print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
  print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)
  print(test_labels)


# Reformat into a TensorFlow-friendly shape:
# - convolutions need the image data formatted as a cube (width by height by #channels)
# - labels as float 1-hot encodings.

# In[38]:

image_size = 28
num_labels = 10
num_channels = 1 # grayscale

import numpy as np

def reformat(dataset, labels):
  dataset = dataset.reshape(
    (-1, image_size, image_size, num_channels)).astype(np.float32)
  #print(np.arange(num_labels))
  labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
  #print(labels[0,:])
  print(labels[0])
  return dataset, labels
train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(train_dataset, train_labels)
valid_dataset, valid_labels = reformat(valid_dataset, valid_labels)
test_dataset, test_labels = reformat(test_dataset, test_labels)
print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)
#print(labels[0])


# In[39]:

def accuracy(predictions, labels):
  return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))
          / predictions.shape[0])


# Let's build a small network with two convolutional layers, followed by one fully connected layer. Convolutional networks are more expensive computationally, so we'll limit its depth and number of fully connected nodes.

# In[47]:

batch_size = 16
patch_size = 5
depth = 16
num_hidden = 64

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():

  # Input data.
  tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels))
  tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
  tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
  tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

  # Variables.
  layer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [patch_size, patch_size, num_channels, depth], stddev=0.1),name="layer1_weights")
  layer1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([depth]),name = "layer1_biases")
  layer2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [patch_size, patch_size, depth, depth], stddev=0.1),name = "layer2_weights")
  layer2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[depth]),name ="layer2_biases")
  layer3_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [image_size // 4 * image_size // 4 * depth, num_hidden], stddev=0.1),name="layer3_biases")
  layer3_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_hidden]),name = "layer3_biases")
  layer4_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [num_hidden, num_labels], stddev=0.1),name = "layer4_weights")
  layer4_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_labels]),name = "layer4_biases")

  # Model.
  def model(data):
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(data, layer1_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer1_biases)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(hidden, layer2_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer2_biases)
    shape = hidden.get_shape().as_list()
    reshape = tf.reshape(hidden, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)
    return tf.matmul(hidden, layer4_weights) + layer4_biases

  # Training computation.
  logits = model(tf_train_dataset)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf_train_labels))

  # Optimizer.
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

  # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
  train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
  valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_valid_dataset))
  test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_test_dataset))


# In[48]:

num_steps = 1001
#saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  print('Initialized')
  for step in range(num_steps):
    offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
    batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :, :]
    batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l, predictions = session.run(
      [optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
    if (step % 50 == 0):
      print('Minibatch loss at step %d: %f' % (step, l))
      print('Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
      print('Validation accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(
        valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
  print('Test accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
  save_path = tf.train.Saver().save(session, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

Everything works fine and the model is stored in the respective folder .

**I have created one more python file where i have tried restoring the model but getting an error there**

```
# In[1]:
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
from six.moves import range


# In[3]:

image_size = 28
num_labels = 10
num_channels = 1 # grayscale
import numpy as np


# In[4]:

def accuracy(predictions, labels):
  return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))
          / predictions.shape[0])


# In[8]:

batch_size = 16
patch_size = 5
depth = 16
num_hidden = 64

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():

  '''# Input data.
  tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels))
  tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
  tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
  tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)'''

  # Variables.
  layer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [patch_size, patch_size, num_channels, depth], stddev=0.1),name="layer1_weights")
  layer1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([depth]),name = "layer1_biases")
  layer2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [patch_size, patch_size, depth, depth], stddev=0.1),name = "layer2_weights")
  layer2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[depth]),name ="layer2_biases")
  layer3_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [image_size // 4 * image_size // 4 * depth, num_hidden], stddev=0.1),name="layer3_biases")
  layer3_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_hidden]),name = "layer3_biases")
  layer4_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [num_hidden, num_labels], stddev=0.1),name = "layer4_weights")
  layer4_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_labels]),name = "layer4_biases")

  # Model.
  def model(data):
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(data, layer1_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer1_biases)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(hidden, layer2_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer2_biases)
    shape = hidden.get_shape().as_list()
    reshape = tf.reshape(hidden, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)
    return tf.matmul(hidden, layer4_weights) + layer4_biases

  '''# Training computation.
  logits = model(tf_train_dataset)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf_train_labels))

  # Optimizer.
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)'''

  # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
  #train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
  #valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_valid_dataset))
  #test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_test_dataset))

# In[17]:

#saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Restore variables from disk.
  tf.train.Saver().restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model restored.")
  # Do some work with the model
```

error that i am getting is :

***No variables to save***

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The error here is quite subtle. In `In[8]` you create a [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph) called `graph` and set it as default for the [`with graph.as_default():`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.as_default) block. This means that all of the variables are created in `graph`, and if you print `graph.all_variables()` you should see a list of your variables.

**However**, you exit the `with` block before creating (i) the [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/client.html#Session), and (ii) the [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver). This means that the session and saver are created in a **different graph** (the global default `tf.Graph` that is used when you don't explicitly create one and set it as default), which doesn't contain any variables—or any nodes at all.

There are at least two solutions:

1. As [Yaroslav suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36282423/3574081), you can write your program without using the `with graph.as_default():` block, which avoids the confusion with multiple graphs. However, this can lead to name collisions between different cells in your IPython notebook, which is awkward when using the `tf.train.Saver`, since it uses the `name` property of a `tf.Variable` as the key in the checkpoint file.
2. You can create the saver *inside* the `with graph.as_default():` block, and create the `tf.Session` with an explicit graph, as follows:

   ```
   with graph.as_default():
       # [Variable and model creation goes here.]

       saver = tf.train.Saver()  # Gets all variables in `graph`.

   with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
       saver.restore(sess)
       # Do some work with the model....
   ```

   Alternatively, you can create the `tf.Session` *inside* the `with graph.as_default():` block, in which case it will use `graph` for all of its operations.

Comment: Thanks mrry for your answer , How can i now pass my image to this model which hence classifies my image , does the code that i have tried to write in the second python file(file in which i was restoring my variables) is correct or does it need modification to be done

Comment: You could try feeding the image data to `tf_valid_dataset` and fetching `valid_prediction`. (It would be easier if `tf_valid_dataset` were a `tf.placeholder()` so you could feed inputs of any size to that tensor.)

Comment: could you please provide a code snippet for the same , Actually i am completely new to Tensorflow and thus facing these small difficulties .

Comment: can u please provide a code snippet , i have tried passing a grayscale image but i am not able to create a 4D Tensor of the image that i have to pass . Please do help me with this

Comment: Happy to help with this, but it's not relevant to the current question. Feel free to add a new question with a snippet of what you've tried, and any error message, and I'll answer.

Comment: @mrry - This is very old but, How does one restore the model for use in production in case of multiple graphs. Do i need to pickle the relevant tf.train.Saver() and use it in production?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'all_variables'`

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new session in `In[17]` which wipes your variables. Also, you don't need to use `with` blocks if you only have one default graph and one default session, you can instead do something like this

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
layer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
  [patch_size, patch_size, num_channels, depth], stddev=0.1),name="layer1_weights")
tf.train.Saver().restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer yaroslav .