# Save wide and deep learning model

Tags: tensorflow

I have used wide and deep learning model for my classification task. I've trained it on training dataset and would like to save it so that I can use it later for prediction purpose. I've tried using :

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver.save(sess, 'wide_n_deep')
```

But all I am getting is :

```
No variables to save
```

Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36281129/no-variable-to-save-error-in-tensorflow

Comment: Yes, I've tried it but its not working.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code to understand and replicate the issue. Thank you.