# Tensorflow ValueError: No variables to save (but there are many)

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to save a model from a graph that I have loaded from disk. I can load the graph and inspect it without issue, and run the training op, but I can't create a saver without getting ValueError: No variables to save.

Graph definition:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from pathlib import Path
import os
import tensorflow as tf

outdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
outfile = Path(__file__).stem + ".pb"

print(os.path.join(outdir, outfile))

# The input is the state of a Tic Tac Toe game.
# This is represented as two length-9 Vec<u8>.
# The first plane holds the location of the first player's stones,
# The second plane, the second player's.
# A 19th byte holds 0 for first player, 1 for second player.
x = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, shape=[None, 9 * 2 + 1], name ='x')

# Training makes makes the net more likely to pick the picked move.
# The picked move will be 1.0, the other 8 spaces will be 0.0.
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 9], name='y_true')

dense = tf.layers.dense(tf.cast(x, tf.float32), units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
logits = tf.layers.dense(dense, units=9, activation=tf.nn.relu)
softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='softmax')

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.variables_initializer(tf.global_variables(), name='init')
sess.run(init)

loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true, predictions=softmax)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss, name='train')

definition = tf.Session().graph_def
tf.train.write_graph(definition, outdir, outfile, as_text=False)
```

Loading the graph:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import glob

num_epochs = 100
minibatch_size = 128
dataset_dir = "src/tictactoe/gamedata"
model_dir = "src/tictactoe/simple_model/checkpoint"
graph_filename = "src/tictactoe/simple_net.pb"

def make_dataset(num_epochs, minibatch_size, dataset_dir):
    files = glob.glob("{}/*.tfrecord".format(dataset_dir))
    print("loading", files)
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100000)
    dataset = dataset.batch(minibatch_size)
    print("loaded data")
    return dataset

def parse(bytes):
  features = {"game": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
              "choice": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature((), tf.float32, allow_missing=True)}
  parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(bytes, features)
  game = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features["game"], tf.uint8)
  choice =  parsed_features["choice"]
  return tf.reshape(game, [19]), tf.reshape(choice, [9])


with tf.gfile.FastGFile(graph_filename,'rb') as f:
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    dataset = make_dataset(num_epochs, minibatch_size, dataset_dir)
    print("loading graph at '{}'".format(graph_filename))

    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    example, label = iterator.get_next()
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='',input_map={'x': example, 'y_true':label})

    init = tf.group(
        tf.global_variables_initializer(), 
        tf.local_variables_initializer(), 
        iterator.initializer, 
        sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('init'))

    train = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('train')
    for name in [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]:
        print(name)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(num_epochs):
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)

        while True:
            try:
                sess.run(train)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break
        save_path = saver.save(sess, model_dir)
        print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
```

Tensorflow throws at `saver = tf.train.Saver()`

I tried to confirm that the graph is restored correctly and the variables it contains are loaded into the current default graph by printing out all the variables in the default graph just above the Saver line. There are hundreds there, including the ones I named by hand in the graph creation file (x, y_true, train, etc.).

The related questions don't seem to be my problem. For instance, the closest related question I found is:
[No variable to save error in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36281129/no-variable-to-save-error-in-tensorflow/36282423#36282423)

The OP's issue was that his variables were in the wrong graph. For mine, there is only one graph, and it definitely contains variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the metagraph if you want tensorflow to recognize the variables; the graphdef itself doesn't have enough information to reconstruct everything. Look at the documentation for [`tf.train.import_meta_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph).